# Extracting a Word after delimiter in scala

Tags: scala

I want to extract a word from a String in Scala

```
val text = "This ball is from Rock. He is good boy"
```

I want to extract "Rock" from the string.

I tried:

```
val op = text.subString(4)
```

`text` is not a fixed length string. I just want to pick first word after "From".

This doesnt give the right word. can anyone suggest.

Comment: Can you give more details on how to work out what is the "right word"? There is no unique delimiter before "Word" so perhaps you mean "before delimiter" rather than "after delimiter"?

Comment: I just want to pick word after "From".. In this case its Rock:.. The String cannot be specific length.

Comment: Do you want to remove each word after the `from` word if the text has multiple form words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
text.drop(text.indexOfSlice("from ")+5).takeWhile(_.isLetter)
```

or more generally

```
val delim = "from "
text.drop(text.indexOfSlice(delim)+delim.length).takeWhile(_.isLetter)
```

The `indexOfSlice` finds the position of the delimiter and the `drop` removes everything up to the end of the delimiter. The `takeWhile` takes all the letters for the word and stops at the first non-letter character (in this case ".").

Note that this is case sensitive so it will not find "From ", it will only work with "from ". If more complex testing is required then use `split` to convert to separate words and check each word in turn.

Comment: Thanks Tim this really works. Can you also tell why `+5` is used?

Comment: That's the length of "from ". `indexOfSlice` finds the start of the delimiter, so this is added to make sure that the delimiter is removed as well. Note that the second version uses `delim.length`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are telling scala to print everything from 4th index to end of string.

In your case you first want to split the string into words which can be done using split function and then access the word you want.

Note: split gives you an array of string and array index begin from 0 in scala so rock would be at the 4th index

This piece of code should work for you. Basically I am using a function to the processing of index of the word that immediately follows a substring (in this case from)

```
val text = "This ball is from Rock. He is good boy"

val splitText = text.split("\\W+")

println(splitText(4))
```

Based on your comment below, I would create a code something like this

```
import scala.util.control.Breaks.{break, breakable}

object Question extends App {
  val text = "This ball is from Rock. He is from good boy"
  val splitText = text.split("\\W+")
  val index = getIndex(splitText, "from")

  println(index)
  if (index != -1) {
    println(splitText(index))
  }

  def getIndex(arrSplit: Array[String], subString: String): Int = {

    var output = -1

    var index = 0

    breakable {
      for(item <- arrSplit) {
        if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(subString)) {
          output = index + 1
          break
        }
        index = index + 1
      }
    }

    output
  }
}
```

Comment: This works. However If i want to take always a word after "from" then what i could do. Also the string is not a fixed string. This fails when the string is : "This ball is a good and is owned from Rock. He is good boy"

Comment: Just to verify my understanding that you want to output the word that immediately follows "from". Is that correct?

Comment: Yes.. Correct. String length can vary.

Comment: and can "from" occur more than once. if yes, do you want the word that immediately follows first "from"?

Comment: Thanks Vikas for your answer. +1 for your quick response

Comment: @vnsingh, i have updated my answer with a piece of code that should work for you

Comment: Thanks Vikas however the sigle liner from Tim is very effective and useful

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are expecting:

```
object Test2 extends App {
  val text = "This ball is from Rock. He is good boy"
  private val words = text.split(" ")
  private val wordToTrack = "from"
  val indexOfFrom = words.indexOf(wordToTrack);
  val expectedText = words.filterNot{
    case word if indexOfFrom < words.size & words.contains(wordToTrack) =>
            word == words(indexOfFrom + 1)
    case _ => false

  }.mkString(" ")

  print(expectedText)
}
```

`words.contains(wordToTrack)` guards the scenario if the `from` word(i.e tracking word for this example) is missing in the input text string.
I have used the partial function along with the filter to get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Much appreciated

Comment: @vnsingh is this what you want?

Answer (score -1):

You probably want something more general so that you can extract a word from a sentence if that word is present in the input, without having to hard-code offsets:

```
  def extractWordFromString(input: String, word: String): Option[String] = {
    val wordLength = word.length
    val start = input.indexOfSlice(word)

    if (start == -1) None else Some(input.slice(start, start + wordLength))
  }
```

Executing `extractWordFromString(text, "Rock")` will give you an option containing the target `word` from `input` if it was found, and an empty option otherwise. That way you can handle the case where the word you were searching for was not found.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Much appreciated

Comment: That doesn't do what the OP asked for, and is too complicated for what it does do. `Option.when(input.contains(word))(word)` does the same thing as this code.